# Performance: how to insert CLOB fast using cx_Oracle and executemany()?

Tags: performance, python-3.x, cx-oracle, oracle12c

cx_Oracle API was very fast for me until I tried to work with CLOB values.

I do it as follows:

```
import time
import cx_Oracle

num_records = 100
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@sid')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.prepare("insert into table_clob (msg_id, message) values (:msg_id, :msg)")
cur.bindarraysize = num_records
msg_arr = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB, arraysize=num_records)
text = '$'*2**20    # 1 MB of text
rows = []

start_time = time.perf_counter()
for id in range(num_records):
    msg_arr.setvalue(id, text)
    rows.append( (id, msg_arr) )    # ???

print('{} records prepared, {:.3f} s'
    .format(num_records, time.perf_counter() - start_time))
start_time = time.perf_counter()
cur.executemany(None, rows)
con.commit()
print('{} records inserted, {:.3f} s'
    .format(num_records, time.perf_counter() - start_time))

cur.close()
con.close()
```

1. The main problem worrying me is performance:

   ```
   100 records prepared, 25.090 s - Very much for copying 100MB in memory!
   100 records inserted, 23.503 s - Seems to be too much for 100MB over network.
   ```

   The problematic step is `msg_arr.setvalue(id, text)`. If I comment it, script takes just milliseconds to complete (inserting null into CLOB column of course).
2. Secondly, it seems to be weird to add the same reference to CLOB variable in `rows` array. I found this example in internet, and it works correctly but do I do it right?
3. Are there ways to improve performance in my case?

UPDATE: Tested network throughput: a 107 MB file copies in 11 s via SMB to the same host. But again, network transfer is not the main problem. Data preparation takes abnormally much time.

Comment: First thing is to measure how fast your network is. You might start by simply transfering 100MB with ftp. This will give you an idea, however oracle uses a different protocol. The next thing is to trace the session.

Comment: @steve, added network speed information: it could be two times faster than here, but the main bottleneck is preparation of CLOB variables.

Comment: The line " rows.append( (id, msg_arr) )    # ???" is part of the loop, this does not seem right. If that does not help, its time to get code coverage performance data for the function. I don't think this problem is related to oracle, but to the implementation of the cx_oracle library.

Comment: @steve, executemany() takes array, wich length indicates how many times operation repeats. If my code not right, does anybody know how to do it right?
It's 100% not related to Oracle because analogous Java code works very fast. I think the same, it's due to implementation of cx_Oracle. If so, what library would be better for my case?

Comment: The only option I see is that you fix the library yourself....

Comment: Are you installing the cx_Oracle from RPM (or MSI)? Maybe a better solution would be downloading the source code of cx_Oracle and compile it on your machine with your own Oracle client. I suggest using Unix or Linux machine rather than Windows.

Comment: I have checked this issue with newer version 5.1.3 of cx_Oracle and in another environment (version 11.2.0.1.0 of client and DB). I've got much better results: ~5 s for prepare step, and 4,5 s for transfer step. While network transfer time is close to expected, I find preparation step too slow however.

Answer (score 0):

Weird workaround (thanks to Avinash Nandakumar from cx_Oracle mailing list) but it's a real way to greatly improve performance when inserting CLOBs:

```
import time
import cx_Oracle
import sys

num_records = 100
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@sid')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.bindarraysize = num_records
text = '$'*2**20    # 1 MB of text
rows = []

start_time = time.perf_counter()
cur.executemany(
    "insert into table_clob (msg_id, message) values (:msg_id, empty_clob())",
    [(i,) for i in range(1, 101)])
print('{} records prepared, {:.3f} s'
      .format(num_records, time.perf_counter() - start_time))

start_time = time.perf_counter()
selstmt = "select message from table_clob " +
          "where msg_id between 1 and :1 for update"
cur.execute(selstmt, [num_records])
for id in range(num_records):
    results = cur.fetchone()
    results[0].write(text)
con.commit()
print('{} records inserted, {:.3f} s'
      .format(num_records, time.perf_counter() - start_time))

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Semantically this is not exactly the same as in my original post, I wanted to keep example as easy as possible to show the principle. The point is that you should insert `emptyclob()`, then select it and write its contents.